# Error in plugin gulp-less: Could not parse alpha in jquery-ui.css

Tags: jquery-ui, gulp, less, gulp-less

I get the following error when I gulp:

```
Error in plugin 'gulp-less'
Message:
    Could not parse alpha in file C:\***\vendor\jquery-ui\jquery-ui.css line no. 1307

Details:
    type: Syntax
    filename: C:\***\vendor\jquery-ui\jquery-ui.css
    index: 37202
    line: 1307
    callLine: NaN
    callExtract: undefined
    column: 23
    extract:    opacity: .003;, filter: Alpha(Opacity=.3); /* support: IE8 */,}
    lineNumber: 1307
    fileName: C:\***\vendor\jquery-ui\jquery-ui.css
```

I use the complete jQuery UI in v1.12.1 and [gulp-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-less) in v3.3.0.

The problem is clear to me, but I couldn't come up with a proper solution.
I searched Stack Overflow but I couldn't find a similar problem (nor answer). I assume this cannot be solved easily. Of course, I do not want to modify the line in the jquery-ui.css file, and updating gulp-less is also not an option in my case. But is there a way to configure gulp-less to handle this somehow? Any hint what I could try is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the line, so Less doesn't try to interpret it? i.e `filter: ~"Alpha(Opacity=.3);" `

Comment: That would probably work, thanks, but as I wrote: I don't consider it a clean option to modify 3rd party source.

Comment: Urg my bad, I read that and then forgot about it. How about writing a small preprocessor plugin that replaces `Alpha(...)` with `~"Alpha(...)"`? It is still modifying 3rd party source, but at least it'll do it reliably.

Comment: I found a great example here: https://github.com/mediafreakch/less-plugin-sass2less/blob/master/lib/index.js